# How to catch org.jboss.weld.context.ContextNotActiveException

Tags: jboss7.x, cdi, jpa-2.0, entitylisteners

I understand that this is a RuntimeException but for my usecase I need to catch it and set some attributes.

Context: I am using JPA EntityListeners for auditing and everything works fine when user accesses the application. The problem occurs when the application is accessed remotely using RemoteEJB. I am using a session object (Credentials which captures the user) in the EntityListener, so when the call is from RemoteEJB and because there is no session it fails as expected. This is the only exception I anticipate so I want to catch it and hardcode the auditing in this RemoteEJB accessing case. But somehow I am not able to catch it. I tried to catch javax.enterprise.context.ContextNotActiveException but to no avail.

```
public class CreateListener {
    @Inject @Named("credentials") private Credentials credentials;
    @PrePersist
    public void setCreateAttributes(Auditable entity){
        try {
            entity.setCreateUserName(credentials.getUserName());
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            entity.setCreateUserName("RemoteEJB");
        }
        entity.setCreateTmstmp(new Date());
    }
}
```

Environment: JDK 1.8, JBOSS EAP 7.1, hibernate-jpa-2.1-api, Hibernate 5.2.12.Final

Any help of alternative approach is appreciated.
TIA
-Avi

Comment: Hmm, the exception slips you because it is thrown *before* you actually enter the method body (e.g. prior to that, Weld tried to inject the parameter and blows up). You could, for instance, work with `Instance<T>` because when doing resolution from there, you should be able to catch the exception like you tried.

Comment: So `Credentials` is a CDI bean annotated with `@SessionScoped`?

Comment: @Nikos, yes you are right.

Comment: @Siliarus, can you please provide more information on how to work with Instance<T>. Are you suggesting me to use instanceof operator? Sorry if it is a dumb question.

Comment: In the app I am currently working we have solved this problem by: (1) having our `Credentials` produced by a producer method of a holder bean (2) an appropriate interceptor (filter for web requests, EJB interceptor for EJBs) creates the credentials and sets it in the holder (3) if the session scope is not normally active for that call, the interceptor activates it. I feel good for 1, 2, but not so good for 3. Perhaps some kind of a custom "AuthenticationScope" would be appropriate.

Comment: @AvinashMoram I was referring to [dynamic resolution/programmatic lookup](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/2.0/cdi-spec.html#programmatic_lookup). If you still won't grasp it, ask again and I can giveyou more detailed answer later (on mobile now).

Comment: @Siliarus, I tried that approach, but I still got ContextNotActiveAxception, this is what I have tried `@Inject Instance<Credentials> pCredentials;
 
 @PrePersist
 public void setCreateAttributes(Auditable entity) {
  Credentials credentials = null;
  if(pCredentials != null) {
   credentials = pCredentials.get();
  }
  if (credentials != null && credentials.getUserName() != null) {
   entity.setCreateUserName(credentials.getUserName());
  } else {
   entity.setCreateUserName(GlobalConstants.STEERS);
  }
  entity.setCreateTmstmp(new Date());
 }`